# Show the Min & Max values for each column of X when X created with make_blobs

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I created a data using make_blobs and apply MinMax_sclaer on it.

```
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=30,n_features=10, centers=2,cluster_std=4, random_state=6)
y[5]=0
y[6]=0
X=np.delete(X, 23, 0)
y=np.delete(y, 23)
print (X.shape)
print(y.shape)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# We initialize our scaler
min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
# We fit our scaler
min_max_scaler.fit(X)
# We transform our X using the scaler we have just fit.
scaled_X = min_max_scaler.transform(X)
#print(scaled_X)
```

I want to show the Min & Max values for each column of X. 
I tried to define a function and call it with apply :

```
def minMax(x):
   return pd.Series(index=['min','max'],data=[x.min(),x.max()])
scaled_X.apply(minMax)
```

I received an error :

> numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'apply'

How can I find the Max and Min for each column?

Comment: `scaled` is a numpy  array, not pandas dataframe.

Comment: Your forgot indentation, should that be the problem? If not, try this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html

Comment: @AerysS It's not indentation, I fixed the code